# Why is my react code erroring when the syntax appears fine?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-error

New to react and trying to convert my current project from pure JS to one that uses React.

This is the code I have

```
var DateApp = React.createClass({

//lots of functions inside here such as:

retrieveMatches(){

},

  render() {
    return (

    )

  }
}) //closing of create class

React.render(
  <DateApp />, document.getElementById('content')
);
```

My errors are the following:

1) as the code is > unexpected token pointing at the closing bracket of the return block
2) if i remove the return block > it points at `<DateApp />, document.getElementById('content')` and says there is syntax error at the beginning of this line?

can't work out what bit I'm missing

Comment: instead of `React.render`  use `ReactDOM.render`

Comment: Are you tranpiling it correctly? If you're getting syntax errors on `<` or `>` it usually means you're foregoing proper transpilation before running it in the browser or on the server.

Comment: @HenrikAndersson yes its possible because of `jsx ` transpilation error